# What's the difference between calling a class decorator on a class instance and on a class definition?

Tags: python, python-decorators, class-decorator

```
class Deco:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __call__(self, test_class):
        def inner_func(whatisit):
            return whatisit
        test_class.method = inner_func
        return test_class

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
@Deco('deco')
class TestClassWrapped:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

test = TestClass('test')
test = Deco('deco')(test)

test_wrapped = TestClassWrapped('test')

print(test.method('whatisit')) >> whatisist
print(test_wrapped == test_wrapped.method()) >> True
```

Why do `test.method` and `test_wrapped.method` return different results ?
It seems that the first argument in `test_wrapped.method` is `self`, while it isn't for `test.method`. Why does it differ from one to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walking through your code step-by-step:

1. You create a regular `TestClass` named `test`.
2. You manually call `Deco` and provide it with `test`, with the line `test = Deco('deco')(test)`.
3. This makes your code go through the `__call__` function, which modifies the passed class `test` to set its `method` attribute to the nested function. It then returns it, and so `test` now contains a successfully modified `TestClass` : calling `test.method('whatisit')` will successfully return `'whatisit'`. Importantly, you're NOT accessing a method here : you're accessing a FUNCTION through an ATTRIBUTE. `self` is passed to every method of classes in Python, but since this isn't a method, it doesn't come into play here. Try printing `type(test.method)`, you'll see `<class 'function'>` and not `<class 'method'>`. Importantly, you've passed an INSTANCE of a `TestClass`, not the class definition itself : and only this instance named `test` has had its `method` attribute set.
4. You then create a `TestClassWrapped` named `test_wrapped`. Upon creating it, it enters the `__call__` once more, passing it `TestWrappedClass` as the `test_class` parameter. Importantly, you've passed a DEFINITION of the `TestWrappedClass`, not an instance of it. Setting `method` here will modify it for every instance of `TestWrappedClass` you'll later create, and can even be accessed without instantiating anything. Try calling `TestClassWrapped.method("abc")` : it will print `abc` without instantiating a `TestClassWrapped` at all. Interestingly, when set in this way, it's not set as an attribute but as a method! Try printing `type(test_wrapped.method)`. This is what I believe to be the source of confusion.
5. In the case of `print(test_wrapped.method())`, you have to remember that every method of instantiated classes take `self` as their first parameter. This means that `test_wrapped.method()` will return `self` : hence why `test_wrapped == test_wrapped.method()`. Note that this doesn't apply to methods called from a class definition, like I've shown earlier. `TestClassWrapped.method("abc")` HAS to take a parameter of some sort (like `abc`), else it will complain it's lacking an argument.

So this is why `test.method('whatisit')` returns `'whatisit'` and doesn't take `self` as parameter, and why `test_wrapped.method()` does return `self`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference isn't how the decoration works, but how calling works. When an instance calls a method defined on its class, as `test_wrapped` does, it always passes `self` as the first argument. Meanwhile, when an object calls an attribute of itself that happens to be a function, but doesn't exist on its class, it calls it without passing `self`. Consider this simple class:

```
class LoudTalker:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.shout_hello = lambda: print("HELLO, I'M {}".format(name.upper()))

>>> john = LoudTalker("John")
>>> LoudTalker.shout_hello()
HELLO, I'M JOHN
```

Note that `john` did not pass `self` to `shout_hello` (which would have thrown the error `<lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`) because `shout_hello` was defined directly on the instance, not on the class.